# Run PHP code if row is displayed using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have PHP code in an id element.
The row can be displayed using id in jQuery.
If the row is hidden I want PHP code not to run because I am creating a report based on user selection.
The problem is that the PHP code always runs whether the row is displayed or hidden.
Also the PHP is displaying data from my database so I am compelled to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the row is hidden" do you mean if the row is set to display=hidden in the DOM or if the database has a value setting it to hidden. You must remember that php cannot access the html after it has been generated. PHP only generates the html and passes it along.

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without example code. If you can add that, flag this for moderator attention to be reviewed. Also, please try to discover your shift key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may just be reading your question incorrectly, but it sounds like you'd like to use jQuery to trigger PHP code once it's finished rendering on the server. This is possible, but maybe not as you think.

PHP's job is done when it generates HTML (or performs other actions), and passes data to the browser. Once the browser has this data (usually just static HTML), then JavaScript's job begins. JavaScript isn't able to "reach back" and call functions in PHP at this point, because the PHP has already finished executing. However, there is another way.

The best way to call PHP code using JavaScript is by using an XMLHttpRequest (XHR). [jQuery provides a great method for doing this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Using a slightly modified example from the document I linked to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'dbCall.php?arg1=foo&arg2=bar',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

This code would call the file `dbCall.php` — which could be passed arguments via GET (`arg1=foo&arg2=bar`) — and then wait for its results. Once the results arrive the `success` callback is fired, which replaces the contents of all elements with class `result` using the data from the `dbCall.php` script. An `alert` call then pops a dialogue up on the screen letting you know this has happened successfully.

Comment: Thanx your post have given me another idea to create dynamic reports on user selection.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I may have helped. Just a note, though: you've asked a number of questions but haven't yet accepted any answers. If you're going to continue using the site, it's a good idea to accept answers to questions, or other users will be less likely to provide answers in the future.